# how to fix sql query in django

Tags: django

I'm not sure how to fix 'likesCounter' query. I want to count all likes from one article. Any help is appreciated.

[image]'

model:

```
class Likes(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="like_article")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='liker_user')
```

view:

```
def article_detail(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
    already_liked = Likes.objects.filter(article=article, user=request.user)
    likesCounter = Likes.objects.filter(article=article, user_id=request.user).count()
    if already_liked:
        liked = True
    else:
        liked = False
    return render(request, 'article/single-article.html', context={'article':article, 'liked': liked,'likesCounter':likesCounter,'already_liked':already_liked})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop the filter where you filter on the user id, so:

```
#                  no user_id=request.user ↓
likesCounter = Likes.objects.filter(article=article).count()
```

You can however combine the tree items in a single query with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Exists, OuterRef
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def article_detail(request, pk):
    qs = Article.objects.annotate(
        likes=Count('like_article'),
        is_liked=Exists(
            Like.objects.filter(article=OuterRef('pk'), user=request.user)
        )
    )
    article = get_object_or_404(qs, pk=pk)
    already_liked = article.is_liked
    likesCounter = likes
    return render(request, 'article/single-article.html', context={'article':article, 'liked': liked,'likesCounter':likesCounter,'already_liked':already_liked})
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! It's working now, I will definitely use the get_object_or_404 as well. Thank you!!!